# How to gracefully support data type change on firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Using Firebase real-time database for quickly starting a project and having it up and running is great.

But when the project is alive and sometimes, later on, you need to update the data type of your custom object models, things can become a little less awesome.

Let's say, I started the project with the following model (kotlin example):

```
@Parcelize
data class CustomModel (
    var customField: Int = 0,
)
```

customField representing a boolean value 0 or 1 but as a number

A few weeks later, I realize this field should probably be a boolean type of field (natively supported by firebase)

So I want to change the above model to:

```
@Parcelize
data class CustomModel (
    var customField: Boolean = false,
)
```

The problem is, I have already added some data with the old format for my `customField` (Int) into my document storage

And using the firebase DataSnapshot's method:

```
@PublicApi
public <T> T getValue(@NonNull Class<T> valueType)
```

result in a `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Int to Boolean`

So the question is simple, how can we handle database schema migration in Firebase?

I know I can just catch the exception, but I need to truly add some custom convertion logic, in order to transform those Ints into Booleans and the other way around in order to be backward compatible with older clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally came up with clean a solution to this data type migration problem.
I was able to leverage the use of kotlin `property delegate` in order to change the type of my data class field.

First, I had to change the type of my property to what data type I wanted to migrate to (in my case from Int to Boolean), and add a custom property delegate:

```
@Parcelize
data class CustomModel (
    private var _customField: Boolean = false,
): Parcelable {
    var customField: Any by FirebaseBooleanDelegate(_customField)
}
```

The role of the property delegate here is: to proxy the read and write access to the now private property `_customField` we changed above. 
We could also have used custom getters and setters.

Here is the code:

```
class FirebaseBooleanDelegate(var isOn: Boolean) : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, Any> 
{

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Any {
        return isOn
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: Any) {
        Log.d("FirebaseBooleanDelegate", "calling setter of ${property.name} with value $value")
        isOn = helperSet(value)
    }
}

private fun <T> helperSet(t: T) = when (t) {
    is Number -> t.toBoolean()
    is Boolean -> t
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
```

In the helperSet method, I have the logic handling the data type migration from Number to Boolean.

Finally and because my dataclass property `_customField` is now private, I had to write a custom parceler for my @Parcelized class or my new private field will not be serialized back to firebase:

```
private companion object : Parceler<CustomModel> {
    override fun CustomModel.write(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeByte((if (customField as Boolean) 1 else 0).toByte())
    }

    override fun create(parcel: Parcel): CustomModel {
        return CustomModel(
                _customField = parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte()
        )
    }
}
```

With all this setup the `Datasnapshot's getValue` method is now able to correctly handle the datatype migration without crashing.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think is to change the datatype of the property. This can be done by querying the database to get all the values of that specific property and store it to a boolean value, according to your logic. If the value is `0` store `false`, if the value is `1` store true. Once you got the values, simply remove the property and ad it again using the correct (boolean) datatype.

**Edit:** If your app is released, you're right, you cannot do this in a single step. In that case you should do the change only when the user opens the app. What's the flow? You do the update with the following mechanism:

Create a new release of your app in which you have the option to convert the datatype of your property. Once the user reads that child, gets the values as an `Int`, store it in a boolean variable, remove the property and add it again correctly.

In this way, the users who are using an old version of you app won't be affected since they are using the `Int` property and the users with the newer version of the app, will use the data correctly.

Comment: Hello Alex, If I do that I will lose backward compatibility with older clients running on the same database

Comment: That is actually what I'm trying to do and I was hoping, I could somehow add my custom logic to the snapshot getValue method. But couldn't find a way to do that

Comment: As far as I know there isn't one since `getValue` only gets the data. It doesn't do any other operations.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I will leave the question open for now if someone comes with an innovative way of doing so

Comment: Sorry Alex, but if If I didn't accept your answer it means it hasn't really helped me.
I'm looking for a way to make custom deserialization from Firebase.
As I told you, I'm leaving the question open in case someone comes by with an innovative way of plugin custom logic around getValue.

Comment: Fair enough but let's see why. What was the problem regarding my solution? What was the expected result?

Comment: I was looking for a more practical answer than a theorized solution. Thanks anyway!